# Charting daily balance

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

I have been trying my hand at Python lately. I have been able to look at code examples and create a custom application that queries a Microsoft SQL Server, pulls out two columns (date, balance) and charts them using pyplot embedded in tkinter for future development.

Because of the "chop and change" nature in which I wrote the code, I know there are plenty of bad practices and am looking for some constructive advice!
(I have removed the SQL script as it is huge)

```
import pymssql
import getpass
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import numpy as np
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def movingaverage(dvalues,window):
    weights = np.repeat(1.00,window)/window
    values = [float(val) for val in dvalues]
    sma = np.convolve(values, weights, 'valid')
    return sma

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Daily balance tracker")

f = Figure(figsize=(10, 7), dpi=75)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

server = "RHYSPC"
user = "rhys"
password = getpass.getpass("Please enter password: ")
print("Loading results, please wait...")

conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "RhysACC")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
SELECT Date, Balance FROM Example -- Not the actual query!
""")

results = cursor.fetchall()

x = [i[0] for i in results]
y = [i[1] for i in results]

yMA = movingaverage(y,31)

j = [0] * len(x)

conn.close()

def pounds(x, pos):
    return '£%1.0d' % x

formatter = FuncFormatter(pounds)

f.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%Y'))
f.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
f.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

a.plot(x, j, color='k', linewidth=2.0)
a.plot(x, y, color='b', linewidth=1.0)
a.plot(x[len(x)-len(yMA):], yMA, color='r', linewidth=1.5)


canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()

canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can change `sma = np.convolve(...)     return sma` into `return np.convolve(...)` and drop one variable with a non-obvious name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `%` for string formatting is deprecated, you should be using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) instead. The `str.format` methods also allows you to do some cool things as well. Here's an example of it in action:

```
# No positional or named arguments
print "{} {}".format("Hello", "world")

# Positional arguments (*args)
print "{1} {0}".format("world", "Hello")

# Named arguments (**kwargs)
print "{word1} {word2}".format(word1="Hello", word2="world")
```

When running the line `Tk.mainloop()`, you should encapsulate it in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details.

These two lines should be moved underneath all of your imports/includes:

> ```
> matplotlib.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
> matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
> ```

I'm also noticing your lack of comments as well. Even if this is a small utility script, I'd still recommend adding comments for clarity.

Finally, a few of your variable names confuse me. For example, `f`, `a`, and `j` are all good examples of names that could be better. Try seeing if you can expand on these.